# Performance while using pandas_udf in pyspark with huge dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a problem while using pandas udf in pyspark, it troubles me so long.

### Background

I have a dataframe like this:

```
+---+-----+----+-----+                                                             
|key|month|col1|col2 |
+---+-----+----+-----+
|  a| 1909| 4.2|-0.25|
|  a| 1910|  2 | null|
|  b| 1908| 3.2| 0.7 |
|  b| 1909| 2.1| 1.2 | 
+---+-----+----+-----+
```

In the dataframe, each different key has multiple rows. For each key, I need to calculate something base on col1 / col2, like avg(col1), max(col2) and so on. So the expected result is:

```
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+                                                            
|key|avg(col1)|max(col1)|avg(col2)|max(col2)|
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  a|      3.1|      4.2|    -0.25|    -0.25|
|  b|     2.65|      3.2|     0.95|      1.2|
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

In this case, I can achieve my goal by using functions in pyspark.sql.functions:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
dataframe.groupBy("key").agg(
    func.avg("col1"),
    func.avg("col2"),
    func.max("col1"),
    func.max("col2")
)
```

But what I need to do is more complicated than **avg** or **max**. For example, I need to calculate **the maximium amount decreased**: **max(of x(2)-x(1), x(3)-x(2),………,x(p)-x(p-1))**, where the x(i) means the value of a column at the ith month for each key.

So the result is base on the indicated column **month** and the value column. So I use pandas_udf to do this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func

columns =["col1", "col2"]

def _mad(key, pdf):
    pdf = pdf.sort_values(by="month")  # sort the values by the month
    transformed = [pd.Series(key, ["key"])]
    transformed.append((-pdf[columns].diff()).max())
    res = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(transformed, ignore_index=True)).T
    return res 
# the udf return a pandas dataframe which have the schema I expected
schema = StructType(...)
transform_udf = func.pandas_udf(_mad, schema, func.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
data.groupby("key").apply(transform_udf)
```

But I found this pandas_udf has a very low performance. Notice that this dataframe is very big that has about 3 **billion** rows: there are 5 **Billion** different key and each key has 6 rows, and 300 columns. It takes me about **5 hours** to finished the job. The dataframe is shuffled into 5000 partitions after groupby and I used 1600 cores. It's unacceptabled and I do more experiments to compared the performance between pandas_udf and pyspark.sql.functions while calculate the avg.

### Experiments

Here is the code:

```
# the version1
dataframe.groupBy("key").agg(
    func.avg("col1")
)

# the version2
def _avg(key, pdf):
    transformed = [pd.Series(key, ["key"])]
    transformed.append(pdf["col1"].mean())
    res = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(transformed, ignore_index=True)).T
    return res
schema = StructType(...)
transform_udf = func.pandas_udf(_avg, schema, func.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
data.groupby("key").apply(transform_udf)

# the version3
def _do_nothing(key, pdf):
    pdf.columns = range(len(pdf.columns))
    return pdf.iloc[0:1]
schema = StructType(...)
transform_udf = func.pandas_udf(_do_nothing, schema, func.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
data.groupby("key").apply(transform_udf)
```

- Version 1

The version1 is very quickly, it takes me about 2 mins 9 secs to finish the job.

Stage0: read the raw data and shuffling into 5000 partitions, cost 2.4 min. The Input size is 406G and shuffle write is **42G**.

Stage1: calculate the avg, cost 9 secs

- Version 2

Stage0 cost about 30mins to read the data and shuffling. It seems that it need to read the whole dataset into memory thought I need only three columns("key", "month", "col1"), the shuffle write is more bigger  than **42G**.

Stage1 takes about 5 hours.

- Version 3

the cost is very similar to version 2, although the udf do nothing and just return the first row of the pdf. So the time is cost in Serialization?

### Question

So it seems that it's very expensive to use pandas udf in pyspark, because of the Serialization? Is there any other ways? The fully functions I need is below:

- avg
- max
- min
- cav, the current vs average: x(1)/mean(of x(1), x(2),…..x(p))
- ltr, the ratio of average in the recent p months to average in recent q months: mean(of x(1), x(2),…….x(p))/mean(of x(1), x(2),……….x(q))
- mad, the maximium amount decreased: max(of x(2)-x(1), x(3)-x(2),………,x(p)-x(p-1))
- mai, the maximium amount increased: max(of x(1)-x(2),x(2)-x(3), ……, x(p-1)-x(p))
- mcd, the maximium consecutive decreasing months: max( of r_ind - l_ind, where x(I_ind)

  mci, the maximium consecutive increasing months: max( of r_ind - l_ind, where x(I_ind)>x(I_ind +1)>…>x(r_ind))

  msn, the month since the most recent positive value:
  =0 if value of most recent month is positive
  =1 if value of 2nd most recent month is positive and most recent month is non positive.
  =2 if value of 3rd most recent month is positive and most recent 2 months are non positive. ....
  =p-1 if the oldest month is positive and all p-1 recent months are non positive
  =p if all months are non positive

  msx, the month since the most recent maXimium value:
  =0 if value of most recent month is the maximum or all months are a non 0 constant
  =1 if value of 2nd most recent month is maximum  .........
  =p-1 if the oldest month is the maximum
  =p if all months are constant 0

  num, the number of positive  months

  cmx, the current vs maximium ratio: x(1)/max(of x(1),x(2),….x(p))

Here is part of my current code:

```
def _derivative(data, primary_key, period_key, num_period, transform_funcs, keep_origin, selected_columns):
    def _transform(key, pdf):
        pdf = pdf.sort_values(by=period_key)
        transformed = [pd.Series(str(key), [primary_key])]
        if keep_origin:
            for _, s in pdf[selected_columns].iterrows():
                transformed.append(s)
        for func_name, columns in transform_funcs.items():
            if func_name in ("msx", "msn"):
                mask = pd.DataFrame([(range(num_period - 1, -1, -1))] * len(columns)).T
                fn = lambda pdf, columns: TRANSFORM_FUNC[func_name](pdf, columns, mask)
            elif func_name == "ltr":
                fn = lambda pdf, columns: TRANSFORM_FUNC[func_name](pdf, columns, 3)
            else:
                fn = TRANSFORM_FUNC[func_name]
            transformed.append(fn(pdf, columns))
        res = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(transformed, ignore_index=True)).T
        return res

    fields = [StructField(primary_key, StringType())]
    if keep_origin:
        for i in range(num_period, 0, -1):
            fields.extend([StructField("{}_h{}".format(column, i), FloatType()) for column in selected_columns])
    for func_name, columns in transform_funcs.items():
        for column in columns:
            fields.append(StructField("{}_{}_0{}M".format(column, func_name.upper(), num_period), FloatType()))
    schema = StructType(fields)
    transform_udf = func.pandas_udf(_transform, schema, func.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    return data.groupby(primary_key).apply(transform_udf)


def _avg(pdf, columns):
    res = pdf[columns].mean()
    return res


def _cav(pdf, columns):
    res = (pdf[columns].iloc[-1] / (pdf[columns].mean()))
    return res


def _ltr(pdf, columns, q):
    res = (pdf[columns].iloc[-q:].mean() / pdf[columns].mean())
    return res


def _mad(pdf, columns):
    return (-pdf[columns].diff()).max()


def _mai(pdf, columns):
    return pdf[columns].diff().max()


def _max(pdf, columns):
    return pdf[columns].max()


def _mcd(pdf, columns):
    diff = -pdf[columns].diff()
    diff[diff > 0] = 1.0
    diff[diff != 1] = 0
    cur = pd.Series(diff.iloc[0])
    mcd = []
    for i in range(pdf.shape[0]):
        cur = (cur + 1) * diff.iloc[i]
        mcd.append(cur)
    return pd.concat(mcd, axis=1).max(axis=1)


def _mci(pdf, columns):
    diff = pdf[columns].diff()
    diff[diff > 0] = 1.0
    diff[diff != 1] = 0
    cur = pd.Series(diff.iloc[0])
    mcd = []
    for i in range(pdf.shape[0]):
        cur = (cur + 1) * diff.iloc[i]
        mcd.append(cur)
    return pd.concat(mcd, axis=1).max(axis=1)


def _min(pdf, columns):
    return pdf[columns].min()


def _msn(pdf, columns, mask):
    pdf = pdf[columns]
    pdf[pdf > 0] = 1
    pdf[pdf != 1] = np.nan
    res = (pdf * mask.values).min()
    return res.fillna(pdf.shape[0])


def _msx(pdf, columns, mask):
    pdf = pdf[columns]
    pdf[pdf != pdf.max()] = np.nan
    pdf[~pdf.isna()] = 1
    res = (pdf * mask.values).min()
    return res.fillna(pdf.shape[0])


def _num(pdf, columns):
    return (pdf[columns] > 0).sum()


def _cmx(pdf, columns):
    return pdf[columns].iloc[-1] / (pdf[columns].max())


TRANSFORM_FUNC = {
    'avg': _avg,
    'cav': _cav,
    'ltr': _ltr,
    'mad': _mad,
    'mai': _mai,
    'max': _max,
    'mcd': _mcd,
    'mci': _mci,
    'min': _min,
    'msn': _msn,
    'msx': _msx,
    'num': _num,
    'cmx': _cmx
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    primary_key = "key"
    period_key = "month"
    num_period = 6
    transform_funcs = {
        'avg': ['col1', 'col2', ...],
        'max': ['col1', 'col2', ...],
        ...
    }
    keep_origin = True
    selected_columns = ['col1', 'col2', ...]
    _derivative(data, primary_key, period_key, num_period, transform_funcs, keep_origin, columns)
```

Also, I tried to change the raw dataframe into something like this and than use a udf rather than pandas_udf:

```
rdd = dataframe.rdd
dataframe2 = rdd.map(...).toDF()
# dataframe2 may looks like below
+---+--------+-------+-------+-------+                                                             
|key||col1_m1|col1_m2|col2_m1|col2_m2|
+---+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|  a|       2|    4.2|   null|  -0.25|
|  b|     2.1|    3.2|    1.2|    0.7|
+---+--------+-------+-------+-------+

# than use a udf
dataframe2.select(avg_udf(func.struct(['col1_m1', 'col1_m2', ...])), udf2(...), ...)
# udf may looks like this
def avg_udf(row):
    return float(np.mean(row))
```

This works better than the pandas_udf but it's still very slowly. Is there any other ways? Thanks all:)

Comment: UDF-s are really slow in general because Spark cannot optimize them, like it does with SQL/premade functions. If possible you should avoid them, and try rewriting your functions in SQL and use something like [`df.selectExpr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr) to apply them. If that is not possible, maybe check out [this article](https://medium.com/@QuantumBlack/spark-udf-deep-insights-in-performance-f0a95a4d8c62), but you may be able to get rid of the udf-s in your case...